# Common Error Page for All Directories in Java Web App

Tags: java, tomcat8, custom-error-pages

I am trying to have a `error.html` error page in my Java WebApp with `web.xml` entry as below:

```
<error-page>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

having a directory listing as:

```
--App
  -- index.html
  -- error.html
  -- css/
     -- ...
  -- js/
     -- ...
  -- img/
     -- ...
  -- folder/
     -- index.html
```

When I enter an address say:

`/App/some-wrong-address` or `/App/folder/some-wrong-address`

In both the cases I am able to see the Error Page called in as part of `404` error, but in *latter* case I am not getting my resources like `caa`, `js`, or `img` pulled up.

I understand that the resources are called relatively with `./...` path and in the second case it is expecting it to be `../...` because of directory change, but I want to OVERCOME this thing, I am not directly working on production server and I cannot use exact URL of everything with `localhost` as it will have to change later everywhere.

Let me know how can I do this?

I am using Tomcat 8.0.28 and WebApp version is `3.1`.

Comment: Would an htaccess 404 redirect be sufficient?

Comment: @Confiqure not sure, I haven't use htaccess in any java Web App before. .

Comment: @Akhil Why `Java` tag removed? how the question is not related to Java?

Comment: @Asif - I agree about restoring the Java tag, however you should remove your _Second Question:_ and the javascript & jquery tags. There should be only one question per question.  Ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to correctly produce all of the HTML that your webapp produces.  The HTML must have the correct URLs (note: they are URLs, not paths) in the elements that refer to other assets (CSS, images, javascript).

You are correct that putting the absolute URL of your production system in your source files is not a workable solution.

In a JavaEE web app I worked on, we used JSF Facelets as the templating system for producing our HTML.  In that we wrote each URL like this:

```
<script src="#{request.contextPath}/foo/bar/baz.js" />
<img src="#{request.contextPath}/img/something.png" />
```

This allows any template, at any location in the URL hierarchy, to reference any asset.  The JavaEE app server handles filling in the correct context path so that the resulting URL the browser handles is correct regardless of where it is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

`application.getContextPath()` will give you page context,and you can base ur urls accordingly after that..will work on local server as well as deplyment server..
e.g: `... href=" <%=application.getContextPath()%>/css/yourcss.css" ...` etc.

N.B.: its a good idea to design your error page in a way that it as no dependencies to any other files..styling and resources in that case should be absolute or inline and images if any should reside in the same folder as your error page